# Store result of query in local variable and send a confirmation for the same in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

My node server is giving me a response for a query result which I want to store in my Angular Service's Local Variable(movie) and pass a confirmation message({"result":true}) to the asking angular component.

```
redirect(id){
    this.movie.getMovie(id).subscribe( confirmation =>{ 
      if(confirmation.result) this.router.navigate(["/movies/movDetails"]);
    });
}
```

This is my angular Component

```
getMovie(id):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/getMovie",{ "_id":id }).subscribe(IncomingValue => this.movie = IncomingValue).pipe(map( return {"result":true} ));
}
```

Service Component

Comment: The service should not be subscribing. The subscribing belongs in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When retrieving data, one often uses a `get`, not a `post`. This is what one of my simple gets looks like:

```
  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl);
  }
```

Using your code ... you can then use RxJS pipeable operators to perform additional operations:

```
getMovie(id):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/getMovie",{ "_id":id })
           .pipe(
              tap(IncomingValue => this.movie = IncomingValue),
              map(() => {return {"result":true}} )
           );
}
```

The first pipeable operator, tap, stores the incoming value in your local property.

The second pipeable operator, map, maps the result as the defined key and value pair.

Hope this helps.